# Поиск двузначных чисел, равные удвоенному произведению их цифр

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Найти все двузначные числа, равные удвоенному произведению их цифр.

Comment: Домашнее задание без попыток решения, наследие хешкода еще. Держать открытым смысла не имеет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if ((i * j) << 1 == (i * 10 + j))
             std::cout << i << j << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Выдает только 36 =)

Comment: а можешь ещё на словах обяснить роботу алгоритма ?

Comment: Перебераем все пары цифр - все возможные двухзначные числа от 10 до 99, если удвоенное произведение первой цифры на вторую равно самому числу (т.е. первая цифра умноженная на 10 плюс вторая), то выводим число, состоящие из этих цифр.

Comment: `3 * 6 == 6 * 3`, по-моему можно сократить первый цикл до 4 итераций(49 - последняя пара)